# iOS background service vibrate phone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have an app that runs in the background (location services). When the app is in the foreground it vibrates fine when I want it to, however, if its not in the foreground (in the multitasking view), the vibrate does not work anymore. Is this not allowed? Is there some way for my background app to give a vibrate alert? If not that what about a beeping sound?

Right now I am just doing something like this:

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

While importing:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Comment: I doubt it's allowed, but who knows, do you have background music enabled in your app's settings ?, however you can still do it some other way, like notifications or something ? what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Im making an app you can control when its in your pocket, so i'd like some way to alert the user that it got activated!

Comment: Vibrate not working in ios 12.1 (iphone 7), If there is any other way then it would be helpfull
- Background audio mode is enable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to provide the user with a notification of something while your app is running in the background, consider delivering that information using a Local Notification (see [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalNotification).)

Forcing the phone to vibrate is not a great user experience for a few reasons:

- Some users (including myself) disable vibrate while in silent mode
- iPads and iPod Touches do not vibrate
- Users may not know what caused the vibration or sound and may not realize to open your app

Local notifications appear to the user in a manner that they can control and will recognize.

If your intention is something besides notifying the user, add that to your question & I'll try to help.

Answer (score 5):

If you enable background audio modes (as documented by Apple at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//qa/qa1668/_index.html) then vibration will happen when the app is in the background state. I just verified that adding the "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay" entry under the "Required background modes" property in the target's properties allows the vibration to work when the app is not in the foreground.

Comment: Adding "App plays audio" to the Required background modes in the Info.plist still works - just tested on an iPhone 5S (iOS 9.1).

Comment: Can somebody confirm this vibrates on background?

Comment: No, on my iPhone 7 (iOS 11.2.5) Sound works on background, but vibration doesn't work((

Answer (score 5):

I found that checking 'Audio,AirPlay and Picture in Picture' within the 'Background Modes' of your apps *Capabilities* worked:

[image]

Comment: This does appear to work. Whether or not it's a good idea is a separate matter!

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that you aren't able to vibrate the phone while it is in the background state.  I've actually never seen an app do this.